# Typescript noImplicitAny for unannotated let

Tags: typescript

When I create a variable whose type changes over multiple assignments, why doesn't typescript warn me about the implicit any?

```js
// This compiles fine with --noImplicitAny
let foo;
foo = "bar";
foo = 2;

// This does not
function (s){
    console.log(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the workings of [PR/11263](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11263). TypeScript is able to determine the type of `foo` by control flow analysis.

```
let foo;
foo = "bar";
foo = 2;

foo
//^? foo: number
```

The type of `foo` would be `number` in this case. Control flow analysis is able to determine the type of `foo` at any reference which leads to no error being reported even if `--noImplicitAny` is set.

A more complex scenario can demonstrate that even the changing the type of `foo` through assignments is perfectly handled by control flow analysis.

```
let a: string
let b: number

let foo;
foo = "bar";
a = foo
b = foo // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

foo = 2;
a = foo // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
b = foo
```

Comment: Ah, so the type changes after each assignment, but that's OK?

Comment: If that is ok really depends to you. But there is no issue regarding type safety.

Comment: There is no type tied to the variable, but the compiler is able to infer it from the last value that was assigned. As Tobias says, there is no type safety problem.